# Cannot log in after disabling Android package from TWRP or with ADB

Tags: twrp, disable-app

I have Google packages on Android disabled for security. Today I enabled the Play Store, Framework, and other stuff and now I can't log in to Android without restarting. I can't remove the package using ADB because it is unauthorized, as I can't log in.

I am rooted and disabled these Google packages. Enabling them seem to restart the phone at login (after you enter the password)

I can get into TWRP recovery, but it doesn't support the `pm` command-line tool.

I need to disable these packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question. If you have a package that is crashing or restarting at boot, you can disable it by using a recovery shell from TWRP. You can disable packages by editing the `/data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml` file and add `inst="false" stopped="true" nl="true"`inside the XML line of the package that is causing the trouble.